# How to remove char '*' from Console Window? Command Console.Write("\b"); didn't work

Tags: c#, string, console, char

This is contain from method, which writes hidden letters. When I hit a backspace, I need somehow to delete char * from console.

```
    private static string Password()
    {
        bool enter=true;
        string pass="";
        do
        {

            char letter = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
            if (letter == (char)13)
            { enter = false; }
            else if (letter == (char)8 && pass.Length >= 1)
            {
                pass = pass.Remove(pass.Length - 1);
                Console.Write("\b");
            }
            else
            {
                pass += letter;
                Console.Write("*");
            }
        } while (enter);
        Console.WriteLine();
        return pass;
    }
```

I searched for an answer but the command Console.Write("\b"); but it doesn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: What are you asking for? Your code outputs the "*". Are you trying to erase it after it is displayed? Windows is not Unix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the cursor's position back one, write a null character, then move it back again. Like this:

```
private static string Password()
{
    bool enter = true;
    string pass = "";
    do
    {
        char letter = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
        if (letter == (char)13)
        { enter = false; }
        else if (letter == (char)8 && pass.Length >= 1)
        {
            pass = pass.Remove(pass.Length - 1);
            Console.CursorLeft--;
            Console.Write('\0');
            Console.CursorLeft--;
        }
        //Additionally, don't print backspaces if it's the first character.
        else if (letter != (char)8)
        {
            pass += letter;
            Console.Write("*");
        }
    } while (enter);
    Console.WriteLine();
    return pass;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Console.Write("\b \b");
```